# Using koa, socket.io, and rethinkdb with node 4.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io, koa

I am curious if anybody has had any luck running koajs with Node 4.0? And if they have had any "*got ya's*" while doing so? I know there are a lot of breaking changes upgrading from older versions of node and io.js, but since the two have now been combined in a single codebase i figure it shouldn't be too hard to get koa working with node 4.0 since the biggest thing needed is generators.

Currently i am useing socket.io with rethinkdb but I get a segmenation fault: 11 when trying to start a socket.io server. Does anyone know a way to get socket.io to work with the new version of Node?

Answer (score 0):

Found a super simple solution that worked from a tweet from @JedWatson.

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`